# Test con PHPUNIT "Class not found" Con namespaces o sin ellos

Tags: php, phpunit

Estoy intentando hacer un pequeño test pero no me está funcionando.

Este es el error que me devuelve:

`Error : Class 'App\Src\Rover' not found`

este es el código de test:

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\Src\Rover;
use App\Src\MovementUtil;

class RoverTest extends TestCase
{

public function testConducirRover()
{
        $start = [0, 0];
        $direction = 'N';
        $command = 'FFFRFLFFFF';
        $grid = [10, 10];
        $obstaculo = [1, 4];

        $rover = new Rover($start, $direction, $command, $grid, $obstaculo);
        $movement = new MovementUtil($rover);
        $result = $movement->moveRover();

        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

La estructura de las carpetas es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las clases están definidas de esta manera:

```
<?php

namespace App\Src;

/**
 * Class Rover
 *
 * @package App\Src
 */
class Rover
{
...
```

Mi composer.json

```
<?php

namespace App\Src;

/**
 * Class MovementUtil
 */
class MovementUtil {
...
```

```
{
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Pavlo Bodnar",
            "email": "pavlobod91@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

Y si ejecuto `php vendor/bin/phpunit` me devuelve este error:

```
dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd "../phpunit/phpunit" && pwd)

if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ]; then
    case $(which php) in
        $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/*)
            # We are in Cygwin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
            dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
            ;;
    esac
fi

"${dir}/phpunit" "$@"
```

Comment: Es un tema de configuración del composer.  Revisa la configuración del psr, quizás tengas que añadir el directorio de tests

Comment: No lo acabo de entender, como añado un directorio ahí?

Comment: En el archivo composer.json, revisa la parte de configuración de psr. Ahí tienes establecido entre otros la relación namespace-directorio. Añade ahí lo que necesites

Comment: Los namespace están mal. La clase `Rover` no existe bajo el namespace `App\Tests` según veo en tu otra pregunta está bajo el namespace `MarsRover`. Mejor junta ambas preguntas por que son el mismo problema y será más fácil ayudarte en una sola que no con la información divididas. Muéstranos tu `composer.json` entero y el `phpunit.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas esta configuración en composer.json (fíjate que añado "Src", porque en tu namespace está en mayúscula pero tu carpeta está en minúscula:

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
       "App\\Src\\": "src/"
   } 
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tuve el mismo error en mi caso la distribución de carpetas es la misma que la tuya, utilizando src y tests como carpetas respectivas para los archivos que quiero probar con phpunit
mi archivo **src/HelloWorld.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Src;


    class HelloWorld {
           public function hello():string
           {
               return 'hello';
           }

    } 


?>
```

**tests/HelloWorldTest.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Tests;
use App\Src\HelloWorld;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class HelloWorldTest extends TestCase{
    public function testHelloWorld(){
        $helloWorld= new HelloWorld();
        $this->assertEquals('hello',$helloWorld->hello());
    }
}
```

**composer.json**

```
{
"require": {
    "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.5",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5"
},
"autoload": {
     "psr-4": {"App\\Src\\": "src/"}
},
"autoload-dev": {
      "psr-4": {"App\\Tests\\": "tests/"}
}


}
```

la solución que me funciono es ejecutar `composer dumpautoload`
mediante linea de comando dentro del proyecto para actualizar la información del cargador automático de clases.
[image: Composer dump autoload]
espero te sirva igual que a mi.

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/300364)